# Is Cloudflare's auto-minify feature compatible with Railgun?

Tags: nameserver, cloudflare, cname

I have burned the last two days wondering why the minification from Cloudflare doesn't work and what is happening. First I thought it was related to caching. Then it got me by reading something remotely connected to my problem somewhere around here or serverfault/stackoverflow that it's related to the Railgun configuration. I'm not even sure if this is the right place for this question.

So, I'm using A2hosting which give Railgun for free but you have to setup your DNS records with a CNAME configuration from their cPanel, use the A2hosting nameservers and use their Cloudflare app.

Before that I was using the nameservers which Cloudflare game me. I guess, the minification service really only works when you are using the Cloudflare nameservers? Is there something else that I'm missing? The information on both sites is kind of vague on what is working and when.

Should I disable the Railgun and go back to using their nameservers for the minification benefit? I think that actually Railgun isn't worth it for my websites, because they aren't being updated dynamically that often - small woocommerce stores, a coppermine gallery and blogs. The whole site minification looks to be of a greater benefit. And yes I have caching plugins installed which minify but the woocommerce stores have some pages that are excluded from caching and this does seem to include exclusion from minification of even the HTML.

To be more clear:
Can Railgun run with Minification enabled?

Comment: To be clear, you appear to be asking about the compatibility of two Cloudflare features: [auto minify](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168196-How-do-I-minify-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-to-optimize-my-site-) and [Railgun](https://www.cloudflare.com/website-optimization/railgun/)

Comment: Found the other question that I was talking about - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536010/how-can-i-see-if-cloudflare-is-minifying-my-html-css-and-js-properly